# Different results of seaborn and statsmodels

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I tried to plot linear regression with 95% confidence interval for the slope and found results are different when comparing both methods.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table

x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = 3*np.random.randn(50) + x
res = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()

st, data, ss2 = summary_table(res, alpha=0.05)
fittedvalues = data[:,2]
predict_mean_se  = data[:,3]
predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp = data[:,4:6].T
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:,6:8].T

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label="data")
plt.plot(x, fittedvalues, 'r-', label='OLS')
plt.plot(x, predict_ci_low, 'b--')
plt.plot(x, predict_ci_upp, 'b--')
plt.plot(x, predict_mean_ci_low, 'g--')
plt.plot(x, predict_mean_ci_upp, 'g--')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(212)
sns.regplot(x=x, y=y,label="sns")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: diff]

By the way, what's the difference between predict_mean_ci_low and predict_ci_low? I can't find the explanation of it in the manual. The part of statsmodels is copied from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116479/calculate-confidence-band-of-least-square-fit).

**Edit:**

According to Josef, Warren Weckesser and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738734/r-in-stats-linregress-compared-to-r-squared-in-statsmodels), I need to add a constant to the OLS version.

By default, OLS in statsmodels does not include the constant term (i.e. the intercept) in the linear equation. (The constant term corresponds to a column of ones in the design matrix.)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table

x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = 3*np.random.randn(50) + x
X = sm.add_constant(x)
res = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

st, data, ss2 = summary_table(res, alpha=0.05)
fittedvalues = data[:,2]
predict_mean_se  = data[:,3]
predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp = data[:,4:6].T
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:,6:8].T

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label="data")
plt.plot(X, fittedvalues, 'r-', label='OLS')
plt.plot(X, predict_ci_low, 'b--')
plt.plot(X, predict_ci_upp, 'b--')
plt.plot(X, predict_mean_ci_low, 'g--')
plt.plot(X, predict_mean_ci_upp, 'g--')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(212)
sns.regplot(x=x, y=y,label="sns")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, the plot looks strange now. Some odd lines and extra legends show up.
[image: pic2]

**Edit2:**

Differences between prediction interval and confidence interval, please see this [web](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals).

**Edit3:**

The exog contains all variables I want to include in the model, including a constant (a column of ones). So, we need to use X[:,1] without the column of ones for plot.

```
ax.plot(X[:,1], fittedvalues, 'r-', label='OLS')
ax.plot(X[:,1], predict_ci_low, 'b--')
ax.plot(X[:,1], predict_ci_upp, 'b--')
ax.plot(X[:,1], predict_mean_ci_low, 'g--')
ax.plot(X[:,1], predict_mean_ci_upp, 'g--')
```

[image: exclude]

Comment: you need to add a constant to the OLS version, your x does not contain a constant and the fitted line has to go through the origin. In the confidence interval there is no uncertainty about the constant.

Comment: @Josef Thanks! I add `X = sm.add_constant(x); res = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()` and it works same now. What's the meaning or effect of the constant? Why is it called 'constant'?

Comment: It's the intercept `a` in the regression line `y = a + b x`. It's called `constant` because it is the same value for all observations. In the formula interface it is called `intercept` by patsy.

Comment: @Josef But, `x` is `independent variables`. why should I set them to `constant` at the same time?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738734/r-in-stats-linregress-compared-to-r-squared-in-statsmodels for a related question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks! I understand it now. Could tell me what's the difference between `predict_ci_low` and `predict_mean_ci_low`?

Comment: @Josef Now, I understand the meaning of constant. But, after adding the `constant`, I got some odd lines and extra legends. How to deal with it?